# Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, nested-forms

I have a sign-up form that uses a nested model. Client can have multiple users, and a `User` belongs to a `Client`. On the sign-up form, I want to be able to register both a client and user at the same time. However, I keep getting the "can't mass-assign" for user, which I don't understand since I have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :users`.

```
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
<%= form_for @client do |client_form| %>
  <% if @client.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% for message in @client.errors.full_messages %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= client_form.label :business_name %>
    <%= client_form.text_field :business_name %>
  </div>


    <%= client_form.fields_for :user do |user_form| %>  
      <div class="field">
        <%= user_form.label :first_name %>
        <%= user_form.text_field :first_name %>
      </div>
      </div>
        <div class="field">
        <%= user_form.label :last_name %>
        <%= user_form.text_field :last_name %>
      </div>  
      <div class="field">
        <%= user_form.label :username %>
        <%= user_form.text_field :username %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= user_form.label :password %>
        <%= user_form.password_field :password %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= user_form.label :password_confirmation %>
        <%= user_form.password_field :password_confirmation %>
      </div>
    <% end %> 

  <div class="actions"><%= client_form.submit %></div>
<% end %>


  class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :business_name
  attr_accessible :users_attributes

  has_many :users
  has_many :items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, allow_destroy: true

  ...
  end

  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :client_id, :first_name, :last_name, :username, :password, :password_confirmation
  belongs_to :client

  has_secure_password
  ....
  end
```

**ERROR**

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error - Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user:
  (gem) activemodel-3.2.11/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:48:in `process_removed_attributes'
  (gem) activemodel-3.2.11/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:20:in `debug_protected_attribute_removal'
  (gem) activemodel-3.2.11/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:12:in `sanitize'
  (gem) activemodel-3.2.11/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:230:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:75:in `assign_attributes'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:497:in `initialize'
  app/controllers/clients_controller.rb:45:in `new'
  app/controllers/clients_controller.rb:45:in `create'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.11/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.11/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__330478543754893527__process_action__2034132490286778675
__callbacks'
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Can you post your exact error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

`<%= client_form.fields_for :user do |user_form| %>`

to

`<%= client_form.fields_for :users do |user_form| %>`

Because client_form references to your client model and the model `has_many :users`, you'll want to make sure when you're using nested form fields, that you have `:users` as the symbol. Also, make sure that you have `attr_accessible :users_attributes` in your client model.

Comment: worth noting that this matters because the input fields will be prefixed with `client[users][0]`, `client[users][1]`, ... instead of `client[user]`

Comment: After changing from :user to :users, the user form attributes no longer appear - only the client form attributes. Also, for your second recommendation, I guess you meant "attr_accessible :users_attributes" instead of "accepts_nested_attributes_for :users_attributes". The former is included in my post. With changing to ":users", do I update to update my "def new" Client controller method? I saw another post including an additional statement, "@client.user = User.new". This didn't work for me.

Comment: It most likely does not appear because you do not have any users associated to the client. Instead, you could use jQuery to inject new form fields or you could do something like `@client.users.build` in your controller. This would generate a new user field. I suggest that you look at railscasts and search for nested forms. Having your user fields disappear is a sign that this is working properly (ironically).

Comment: Hi Kobaltz, your suggestion worked (ie, adding `@client.users.build` for def new in controller and `fields_for :users`)! I greatly appreciate your input!!! I wished more online examples linked the 3 areas together.  Could you clean up your original answer to include your latest recommendation (include in `@client.users.build` so user form fields appear) and also remove your reference to accepts_nested_attributes_for (which is in my original post) or replace with `attr_accessible :users_attributes` so I can flag your response as the answer?

Comment: There is a great resource that you can use http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 that explains how this is set up as well as the javascript option.

Answer (score 1):

In your client model try to add this method:
def initialize(*args)
 self.users.build
end

OR

In your controller new action add:
@user = @client.users.build

Comment: Hi Nilay, your response `@user = @client.users.build` also solves the problem but will be flagging kobaltz response, which overlaps with yours, as the answer. Thanks for your insights and helping to resolve this issue!! I might be posting another question on how to set a default user model value when user is nested with client (I imagine setting the default user attribute somewhere in the client model). Thanks again!!

Answer (score -1):

Just a guess, but does it help to change either one or both of these lines?

```
attr_accessible :users_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, allow_destroy: true
```

to

```
attr_accessible :user_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, allow_destroy: true
```

Comment: No, I get error "No association found for name `user'. Has it been defined yet?" I guess since I have "has_many :users". But even if I change it to "has_many :user", the user form attributes not longer appear.